# 'characters is unavailable' please use string directly

Tags: swift, character

I can't figure out how to fix it. I just want to understand how it works and what should be replaced.

I've already tried to delete `characters.`, but it still doesn't work.

```
import Foundation
var shrinking = String("hello")
repeat {
    print(shrinking)
    shrinking = String(shrinking.characters.dropLast())
}
while shrinking.characters.count > 0
```

I expected the program to output:

> hello
>   hell
>   hel
>   he
>   h

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: “I've already tried to delete `characters.`, but it still doesn't work.” ... That’s funny, because when you remove those two `characters` references, it works fine. Rather than just telling us it “doesn’t work”, why don’t you tell us what it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as it is if you delete the `characters` I suggest you create a new playground file. Btw you can simply use `RangeReplaceableCollection` mutating method `popLast` and iterate while your string is not empty to avoid calling your collection count property multiple times:

```
var shrinking = "hello"
repeat {
    print(shrinking)
    shrinking.popLast()
} while !shrinking.isEmpty
```

This will print

> hello
>
> hell
>
> hel
>
> he
>
> h

or using `removeLast` method but it requires the string not to be empty so you would need to check if the string is empty at before the closure:

---

```
var shrinking = "hello"

while !shrinking.isEmpty {
    print(shrinking)
    shrinking.removeLast()
}
```